# Cannot read form input value | nodejs | express | express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I tried to receive the input value from the user through form request using express handlebars. I get the following error.

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'personname' of undefined**

The following pictures contain the code snippets

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9SGN.png) [home.handlebars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND5tz.png)

Please Help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express won't parse `req.body` for you by default. You need middleware, preferably [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

```
const app = require('express')()
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm